How do I update my system to overcome an interrupted Synaptic Manager process?
I was trying to download the Nord VPN installation app and it couldn't download due to ongoing Synaptic Manager processes. When I opened the SM, it didn't show that there were any processes ongoing, so I tried the following command in the terminal:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
The response was this block of text:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-netplan:
 python3-netplan depends on libnetplan1 (= 1.0-2ubuntu1.2); however:
  Version of libnetplan1:amd64 on system is 1.0-2ubuntu1.1.

dpkg: error processing package python3-netplan (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netplan-generator:
 netplan-generator depends on libnetplan1 (= 1.0-2ubuntu1.2); however:
  Version of libnetplan1:amd64 on system is 1.0-2ubuntu1.1.

dpkg: error processing package netplan-generator (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-netplan
 netplan-generator

I think that means I need to update from the 1.1 to the 1.2, but I'm not very good with coding so I could be way off. What should I do? I'm just trying to stop any processes that my computer may be doing so I can install my VPN.

"Downloading" has no interaction with synaptic. Were you actually trying to "install" NordVPN?
